# Laravel - FPDF error: Undefined font

Tags: php, laravel, fpdf, laravel-5

## O que estou fazendo

Estou reescrevendo um pequeno sistema de geração de código de barras usando o Laravel.

## O que deu errado

Estou instanciando as classes normalmente, mas quando uso o método `$pdf->SetFont('Arial','B',$fontSize);` eu recebo a mensagem **FPDF error: Undefined font: helvetica B**. Como podem ver na imagem abaixo, a pasta "font" já está incluída dentro da pasta da biblioteca. Entrei dentro da biblioteca e procurei o método **SetFont**, e só mudei o caminho da pasta, já que o arquivo da lib e e font está dentro do meu diretório.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

## Meu Código

Deixarei apenas pequenas partes do código

```
<?php namespace App\Http\Controllers;

//Declaração de uso de elementos para layout, bibliotecas e depois model com bd
use View, Input, Validator, FPDF, eFPDF, BarcodeClass, BarcodeEAN, DB, App\Models\Barcode;

class HomeController extends Controller {

public function index() {
    return view('frontend.home');
}

public function gerarPdf() {

    //parte inicial do código

    //Cria um novo PDF
    $pdf = new eFPDF('P', 'pt');

    //Modifica informações de visualização do PDF
    $pdf->SetFont('Arial','B',$fontSize);
```

Dentro da classe FPDF.php ele possui o método abaixo que é chamado para importar as fontes.

```
function _getfontpath()
{
    if(!defined('FPDF_FONTPATH') && is_dir(dirname(__FILE__).'font/'))
        define('FPDF_FONTPATH',dirname(__FILE__).'/font/');
    return defined('FPDF_FONTPATH') ? FPDF_FONTPATH : '';
}
```

Comment: Acredito que essa e a melhor solução
[Solução em inglês](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14151317/undefined-font-in-fpdf)

Comment: @AdrianoCarvalho Sim, ele está com uma classe que estende PDF :S, está do modo que está nesse texto.

Comment: Você chegou a definir o diretório das fontes do FPDF `define('FPDF_FONTPATH','font/');`? A classe não tem um método *constructor*?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Primeiramente: o método `getPath` estava sendo chamado porém o `define` não estava recebendo o caminho completo da pasta. O dirname dele não estava funcionando, então troquei por `app_path().'/Libraries/FPDF/font/'`, e ao final do método gerarPdf logo depois do `$pdf->Output` eu coloquei `exit;` caso contrário o navegador iria mostrar os caracteres abaixo:

%PDF-1.3 3 0 obj <> endobj 4 0 obj <> stream x�e��N�0��} �R<��?W$@�g(�g^�� ��r���~��w&)����Z�^�cx;Ώ��g���G���W|�E> ���i̔4c{��:� r�+���L&�Ʉ޽s"Hh&h�F2c�2��nڢ�,���"���L��<�i ��e�i � +I�φi���i4;,��ۜf�:���۝� ���$<4�9�9��qE���Q�M�i&21���n�^X�~��N+{�)O�yi�tVL�Y��*�f����]Hjj�t#M�B���m�6��>r^��-��WN^�[*7��F�U��F�1�b���f,�9y��>��|�k�^�~r[L�m�l?/��U�n��KxY�G7�x��(�ak�6r���V��T��=��sc�6{� endstream endobj 5 0 obj <> endobj 6 0 obj <> stream x�e��N�0��} �<��?W$@�g(�g^����o{i��~��w�I��k������W�%ư��˺݉�����qW۵��%�p ���ڋ|6�Ә)i���u��4�WN1�L6� �{�D6��L�L�d��2���m�L�k�JIiy& Of��[��q�έa�d%����q@6�A�c�:z���؄��t�v� �� ���$vh@s@s�R�)b�Gy[�(O30����Lts����s�7Z��Lyb̓H��3�bb���gV�4�'��h��B�P�P��э4�����Q�H����ڕ�R��y��R�qb���w޸kL��y��-��;��L��t>�{���-F[>��K�����cW+˰-S׶���M-�-�ǰ~^߮?(V~� endstream endobj 7 0 obj <> endobj 8 0 obj <> stream x�e��N1��<�Kh��w[$@��g"5�υ3���I��|��z'���S\Jߧ�-<�*�/1��^����~���r���$�����Q�Q��8�l��;�?���d��s\�L�e&Wh�D6��\�6�I3�@&�I$3Ι1����Y�Y�L��8ςK��� mq�R1ۊn+��n� �6t۠m�ۆn;���6�m�l;��趻�vxvȠ��ӰC�M0h��"F�����Q�f`"���+�b%�j�7Z��L�ʘ�"�����#+�Y%�̞�!��L:ӛ��n����}z����y��m�켲�귥�ƘG1�C<э��L�����1����)���ۧSƙ3�b���N��ߟ����-/V�L]e�%> endobj 10 0 obj <> stream x�e��N1��<�Kh���n����!H�Լ>�H�-M�U�ˌ�;��Oq��O�kxzUP_b�9���7q��v���뵵�%�p v/��"E���i̔4c{��:� r�+���L�:� �{�DHh&h&#�5�d�E����Z�R�9+4k�Ɋ�U�Y1���4�V7���mp�ඹ�5���Nf����n͹����n�������i���&��C��"&z�����4����Dw^ �pWGy��=͔'�<��O:+&V��|f�I3{b���.����y��4����w�v%]ݟ��nܖF�ΛߖF�Ɖ'ּs��Ÿ-�w��V�sFQ>�b45�|йO����}4������������e�-S׶���Gj���������~� endstream endobj 1 0 obj <> endobj 11 0 obj <> endobj 2 0 obj << /ProcSet [/PDF /Text /ImageB /ImageC /ImageI] /Font << /F1 11 0 R >> /XObject << >> >> endobj 12 0 obj << /Producer (FPDF 1.6) /CreationDate (D:20150326120906) >> endobj 13 0 obj << /Type /Catalog /Pages 1 0 R /OpenAction [3 0 R /FitH null] /PageLayout /OneColumn >> endobj xref 0 14 0000000000 65535 f 0000002164 00000 n 0000002371 00000 n 0000000009 00000 n 0000000087 00000 n 0000000542 00000 n 0000000620 00000 n 0000001077 00000 n 0000001155 00000 n 0000001619 00000 n 0000001698 00000 n 0000002269 00000 n 0000002476 00000 n 0000002552 00000 n trailer << /Size 14 /Root 13 0 R /Info 12 0 R >> startxref 2656 %%EOF

Answer (score 0):

O que seria esse eFPDF ?

Um exemplo seria assim

```
public function gerarPdf() {       
      $fpdf = new Fpdf();
             $fpdf->AddPage();
             $fpdf->SetFont('Arial','B',16);
             $fpdf->Output();
             exit;
}
```

Comment: No link que você me mandou o cara criava "class pdf extends FPDF", e chamava o construtor da classe pai. Ess meu ePDF é a mesma coisa, ele seria o "pdf" usando esse exemplo.

Comment: https://github.com/xroot/laravel-fpdf

Comment: Esse dai deu problema com o repositório na hora de rodar o composer update.

Comment: Desculpe sair fora do assunto!
Qual foi o erro de composer ?

Comment: http://s15.postimg.org/uitl181vv/composer.png - o erro
http://postimg.org/image/m2g81g3rv/ - meu composer

Comment: O erro em questão e lib em "dev-master"! 
Tenta colocar suas lib tudo em dev-master ou tudo com sua ultimas versão...
O problema no erro é que ta dando erro de incompatibilidade  com a lib "illuminate/support": "5.1.*@dev" do laravel 5 com a illuminate que tem depedencias 4.0.1

Comment: Fiz isso e ainda deu erro - http://s13.postimg.org/nfoa7srjr/composer.png, imagem do meu composer.json. Ainda falta alguma coisa ?